# pip upgrade fails - "No files were found to uninstall"

Tags: python, pip

Something goes completely wrong with the `pip` installation on my Mac OS X 10.11.3.

When i use `pip -V` i get the following:

```
***:Desktop ***$ pip -V
pip 8.0.2 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
***:Desktop ***$
```

But when i use `pip list` i get this:

```
***:Desktop ***$ pip list
...
pip (7.1.2)
...
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

And when i try to update `pip` this happens:

```
***:~ ***$ sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.2MB 344kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 7.1.2
    Can't uninstall 'pip'. No files were found to uninstall.
Successfully installed pip-7.1.2
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Any idea how i can figure out what goes wrong / How to solve this mess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you just download pip 8.0.2 from github then install it from commandline?

```
$ wget https://github.com/pypa/pip/archive/8.0.2.zip
$ unzip 8.0.2.zip
$ cd pip-8.0.2/
$ python setup.py install
```